# How do I fetch entire details of table?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a Table named `person`. 
I used all the Connection details. I am able to fetch the data but only one column I am able to fetch. How do I fetch the entire details using foreach loop exactly like how it fetch using query?

Within one Click of Button entire data should be fetched and shown in listbox

code :

```
    string connectionstring = OracleConnString(textBox4.Text,textBox5.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);
    string sql = "select * from person";

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionstring)) // connect to oracle
    {
        conn.Open(); // open the oracle connection
        using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, conn)) // create the oracle sql command
        {
            using (OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader()) // execute the oracle sql and start reading it
            {
                while (rdr.Read()) // loop through each row from oracle
                {
                    //  Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
                    //  Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0); ); 
                    //  Console.WriteLine(rdr["column_name"]); 

                    listBox1.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
                    listBox1.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(1));
                    listBox1.Items.Add(rdr.GetString(2));
                }
                rdr.Close(); // close the oracle reader
            }
        }
        conn.Close(); // close the oracle connection
    }

}


public string OracleConnString(string host, string port, string servicename, string user, string pass)
{
    return String.Format(
      "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})" +
      "(PORT={1}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={2})));User Id={3};Password={4};",
      host,
      port,
      servicename,
      user,
      pass);
}
```

Comment: Now you are getting a record and creating three listbox rows. If you want to display a whole record in a single row it is better to use a more specific control like a DataGridView or the grid equivalent for your UI

Comment: ya i know but i want in listbox using foreach loop

Comment: Then get the three columns and join them together in a single string separating each 'column' with a tab ("\t")